Dynamically loading a JDBC driver in Jenkins
In order to establish a MySQL connection I placed JDBC driver jar file to classpath:
/var/lib/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar

When I am running Groovy code in Jenkins I get the error No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://database/table. However, if I restart Jenkins it will find the driver no problem.
I believe the reason to that behavior is that I placed the driver into classpath after JVM started. So it has to be restarted in order to load the class.
Here is my code:
String url = "jdbc:mysql://host:port/db"
Properties info = new Properties()
info.setProperty("user", "${username}")
info.setProperty("password", "${password}")
info.setProperty("useSSL", "true")
info.setProperty("serverSslCert", "/path/to/cert")
Connection maildDbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, info)

How can I load the class dynamically?

Just curious, why would you need to connect to a database from Jenkins Groovy scripts?

In the prehistoric times we used to do a Class.forName("fully.qualified.jdbc.driver.ClassName") before DriverManager.getConnection(). Assuming Jenkins has no better way (I dont know), Class.forName has a variant that accepts a ClassLoader. If you define a URLClassLoader with the URL of the JDBC driver jar and the current classloader (e.g. Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()), you will probably be able to load the driver class. Not sure if the system will find it, but it may be worth a try. But, do you really need to get into all this trouble? Why???
